# Passing strongly typed Hubs in SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I've just updated some SignalR references and things have changed somewhat in order to allow for generically typed Hubs `Hub<T>`. In the existing examples and documentation such as at:

[Server-Broadcast-with-Signalr](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr-20)

we have a static class holding references to clients via the following mechanisms:

```
public class StockTicker()
{
private readonly static Lazy<StockTicker> _instance = new Lazy<StockTicker>(
            () => new StockTicker(GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<StockTickerHub>().Clients));

 IHubConnectionContext Clients {get;set;}

 private StockTicker(IHubConnectionContext clients)
        {
            Clients = clients;
        }
}
```

So a static reference is checked and if null it reaches out to :

```
GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<StockTickerHub>().Clients
```

to create an instance and supply the clients via the constructor.

*So this was how it used to work* and indeed is how the url above has it. But now with `Hub<T>` there is a slight change required in the constructor:

```
 private StockTicker(IHubConnectionContext<dynamic> clients)
 {
   Clients = clients;
 }
```

Now my question is how can I extend this further such that my version of StockTicker can have a strongly typed property for clients of type x.

```
 IHubConnectionContext<StockTickerHub> Clients {get;set;}

 private StockTicker(IHubConnectionContext<dynamic> clients)
 {
   Clients = clients; // Fails, wont compile
 }
```

By maintaining strongly typed references I would be able to call strongly typed methods, etc.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is now a new overload of GetHubContext that takes two generic parameters. The first is the Hub type like before, but the second generic parameter is TClient (which is the T in `Hub<T>`).

Assuming that StockTickerHub is defined as follows:

```cs
public class TypedDemoHub : Hub<IClient>
```

Then

```
GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<StockTickerHub>().Clients
```

becomes

```
GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<StockTickerHub, IClient>().Clients
```

The type returned by the new overload to GetHubContext would be `IHubContext<IClient>` and the Clients property would be `IHubConnectionContext<IClient>` instead of `IHubConnectionContext<dynamic>` or `IHubConnectionContext<StockTickerHub>`.

Comment: Requires SignalR 2.1.x or later.

Comment: oops - Make sure you put `public class TypedDemoHub : Hub<IClient>` and not `public class TypedDemoHub<IClient> : Hub`

Answer (score 12):

In **.NET Core Web App** you can **inject strongly typed signalR hub context**  like this

```cs
public interface IClient
{
    Task ReceiveMessage(string message);
}

public class DevicesHub : Hub<IClient>
{
}

public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IHubContext<DevicesHub, IClient> _devicesHub;

    public HomeController(IHubContext<DevicesHub, IClient> devicesHub)
    {
        _devicesHub = devicesHub;
    }       

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
       _devicesHub.Clients
          .All
          .ReceiveMessage("Message from devices.");

       return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or take look at:

https://github.com/Gandalis/SignalR.Client.TypedHubProxy

It comes with more features than the TypeSafeClient mentioned above.

Comment: This looks very cool.  One of the things that gets hairy with the SignalR C# client is that all of the hub method calls are "stringly-typed", e.g. hubProxy.Invoke("SomeMethod").  It's not hard to typo that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

https://github.com/i-e-b/SignalR-TypeSafeClient

May be useful!

Comment: Neither this one or the above work with PCL profile 111 though, used for Xamarin.Forms.